# Cross Origin Domain Blocking error with AJAX

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong:

I'm using the following code and getting a Cross Origin Domain Blocking error. And no I don't have the ability to enable CORS on the Server Im getting data from. But when I use the URL by itself, I get the data I am after, it's just not working with AJAX, Im trying to use JSONP to get around the issue:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                      url: "https://serveraddress/remote-json.cfm?do=gettimetable",
                      dataType: "jsonp",
                      jsonpCallback: "logResults"
            });
        });
```

kind regards,
Brad

Comment: See the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141

Answer (score 0):

You can use back-end to solve this problem. This back-end(php, java, nodejs, curl...) implement a httpclient to getting data from any server.

I try to set "useDefaultXhrHeader: false", it is the configuration ajax.